# Search nested array for certain criteria

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a report document that has an images array in it.  Inside each image is a thumbnails array that track the thumbnails I have generated for the image.

```js
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("536021ba9b319f5195000004"),
  "images": [{
    "name": "some_image.jpg",
    "width": 1200,
    "height": 1200,
    "thumbnails": [{
      "name": "some_image_150.jpg",
      "size": 150
    }]  
  }]
}
```

Now lets say I want to generate the following thumbnail sizes:

```
[150, 320, 800]
```

Is there a way that I can query the reports collection and get back all reports that do not have all the proper thumbnails generated?  I.E. in the example above, the query would return the example document as it has an image that does not contain all the proper attachments.

Best case would be to only get images where all thumbs are not generated, ie if a report has 2 images and one image has all the thumbnails and another image does not it would be nice to just get the image that needs thumbnails.

I have tried messing around with aggregation to unwind the images array, such that I can match against things.  However I am running in a problem with trying to match the numbers in my array [150, 320, 800] to the documents in thumbnails.

**EDIT:**

I also need to determine if a thumb should not be created.  I.E. if my original image is 350x350, then I should not create a 800x800 thumbnail.  so even though 800 is in my thumbnail set I need to only take values from that thumbnail set that are less than the original images width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to be working on a negative case of the [**`$all`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator combined with [**`$not`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/):

```js
db.collection.find({
    "images.thumbnails.size": {
        "$not": { "$all": [ 150, 320, 800 ] }
    }
})
```

Possibly in versions prior to MongoDB 2.6 you might need to adapt this due to a change in the logic for [**`$all`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) but the same thing is constructed using [**`$and`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/):

```js
db.collection.find({
    "$and": [
        { "$ne": { "images.thumbnail.size": 150 } },
        { "$ne": { "images.thumbnail.size": 320 } },
        { "$ne": { "images.thumbnail.size": 800 } }
    ]
})
```

Noting of course that these statements are matching "documents" and not the elements of your "images" array, to actually filter those you would need to apply this to aggregate:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Match the documents meeting the conditions
    { "$match": {
        "images.thumbnails.size": {
            "$not": { "$all": [ 150, 320, 800 ] }
        }
    }},

    // Unwind the images array
    { "$unwind": "$images" },

    // Filter out any array elements that do not match
    { "$match": {
        "images.thumbnails.size": {
            "$not": { "$all": [ 150, 320, 800 ] }
        }
    }},


    // Optional: Projection re-shaping
    { "$project": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "images": {
                "name": "$images.name",
                "width": "$images.width",
                "height": "$images.height"
            }
        },
        "thumbs": "$images.thumbnails"
    }},

    // Optional: unwind the thumbnails
    { "$unwind": "$thumbs" },

    // Optional: group back only the sizes
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "thumbs": { "$push": "$thumbs.size" }
    }},

    // Optional: Project with the difference on the set
    { "$project": {
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "images": {
            "name": "$_id.images.name",
            "width": "$_id.images.width",
            "height": "$_id.images.height",
            "missingThumbs": { "$setDifference": [
                 [ 150, 320, 800 ],
                 "$thumbs"
            ]}
        }
    }},

    // Restore the images array
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "images": { "$push": "$images" }
    }}

])
```

So this uses [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) to take this a little further and tell you which of the "thumbnail sizes" you were testing for did not exist. The stage is optional as that operator is only available from MongoDB 2.6 and upwards, so otherwise just remove the stages marked as "Optional:" to allow this to filter the "images" array entries.

You also could do the "difference" matching in versions prior to 2.6 but it is a fair bit more involved, but you may want to try and work that part out.

---

As for your full generation edit here would be the full listing:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Match the documents meeting the conditions
    { "$match": {
        "images.thumbnails.size": {
            "$not": { "$all": [ 150, 320, 800 ] }
        }
    }},

    // Unwind the images array
    { "$unwind": "$images" },

    // Filter out any array elements that do not match
    { "$match": {
        "images.thumbnails.size": {
            "$not": { "$all": [ 150, 320, 800 ] }
        }
    }},

    // Projection re-shaping
    { "$project": {
        "_id": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "images": {
                "name": "$images.name",
                "width": "$images.width",
                "height": "$images.height"
            }
        },
        "thumbs": "$images.thumbnails"
    }},

    // unwind the thumbnails
    { "$unwind": "$thumbs" },

    // group back only the sizes
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "thumbs": { "$push": "$thumbs.size" }
    }},

    // Project missingThumbs
    { "$project": {
        "missingThumbs": { "$setDifference": [
             [ 150, 320, 800 ],
             "$thumbs"
        ]}
    }},

    // Unwind the missing thumbs
    { "$unwind": "$missingThumbs" },

    // Project a size test
    { "$project": {
        "missingThumbs": 1,
        "larger": { "$gte": [ 
            "$_id.images.width",
            "$missingThumbs"
        ]}
    }},

    // Match the size test
    { "$match": { "larger": true }},

    // Group back the missing thumbs
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id",
        "missingThumbs": { "$push": "$missingThumbs" }
    }},

    // Project the images entry
    { "$project": {
        "_id": "$_id._id",
        "images": {
            "name": "$_id.images.name",
            "width": "$_id.images.width",
            "height": "$_id.images.height",
            "missingThumbs": "$missingThumbs"
        }
    }},

    // Restore the images array
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "images": { "$push": "$images" }
    }}

])
```

Nothing optional in here as you would clearly be using the features to detect the thumbnails you don't already have. The additional steps are there to compare the size of the missing thumb against the size of the image. Anything not detected as "larger" would be excluded.

Comment: Awesome!  However I am confused about steps 1 and 3 in your aggregation pipeline. They seem to do the same thing. IE filter out all thumbnails not in my set. Why do I need both?

Comment: @lostintranslation First is to filter documents that just won't match so there is no point working on them. Second is after the array contents are found you take out the elements from within the document that wouldn't match. Skipping the first match causes additional workload that is not required, so it is the best way to optimize when matching inside an array. This is also why aggregate is different to find in terms of filtering the inner array.

Comment: I think I see now. First matches documents, which contains all thumbs. Second unwinds. Third filters out thumbs that were part of document match.

Comment: @lostintranslation That is right. So that is the essential difference between the results you can obtain with find as documents will still contain array entries that do not match. But again, the reason for doing it twice is so you are not processing documents in the collection that do not even match the conditions with the $unwind. That part can be very expensive over a whole collection, so you match first as well. Anyhow, it depends on what you want. I generally surmised that you did not need array entries that already had the required thumbnail sizes.

Comment: Any idea on how to dynamically restrict the set of thumbs I want to generate such that the array is all values less than image.width, or image.height. I.E. I am not scaling thumbnails up, so if my image is 150x150, I would not create a 320, or 800 thumbnail. Can I pass mongo [150, 320, 800] - and value that is greater then my image width or image height?  -check edit in post

Comment: @lostintranslation Really should have been another question but is not that much difference to the missing thumbnail detection I already offered. There is an additional listing containing the extra steps.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51844/discussion-between-lostintranslation-and-neil-lunn)

Answer (score 3):

I believe following should work fine for your scenario:

```js
db.mycollection.find( {"images.thumbnails.size": {$not: {"$all": [150, 320, 800]}}  })
```

This should give you any document that does not has one or more of those thumbnail sizes.